# $_Files[] array only showing first file uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, input

I currently have a form with a single file upload input on it.

the original form input I've tried

```
<input type="file" name="userFile[]" />  
and  
<input type="file" name="userFile1" />
```

I also have a link to generate more input fields using

If have tried methods of:
a)

```
counter = 1;  
    function addInput(){  
counter ++;  
    $('#divName').append('&lt;input type="file" name="userFile[]" ' />);        
}
```

b)

```
var counter = 1;  
function addInput(){  
counter++;   
$('#divName').append('&lt;input type="file" name="userFile'+counter+'" ' />);   
}
```

I don't think the issue is JS related here but possibly the server I think.

The issue is that when I finally press the Submit button and pass the files to the server and try to access all the `$_FILES['userFile']['name']`/`['size']`/`['error']` etc values, only the very first original form upload values can be echoed/printed. I tried uploading large size files for testing I know that all files are getting uploaded but once it gets to the server side, only one can be accessed.

Can anyone give me a point as to what might be going on?
I hope I explained this right, ask me any questions if you need clarification.

**more info**

after some more testing it looks like Jquery might be the issue after all.
In the above method mentioned of duplicating the fields, only the first original input is recognized when the files are uploaded.

But if I create three original input fields and upload to them as normal then all files in the `$_FILES` array are recognized as they should be.

So why are the jQuery generated fields not posting in the form?

Comment: Have you checked through [the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)?  In particular the note about `max_file_uploads`?

Comment: Do I understand right, that you try to iterate over `$_FILES['userFile']['name']` array? Try to iterate over `$_FILES['userFile'] instead.

Comment: even if I only print_r the entire $_FILES array it only gives me the first file uploaded as such: Array ( [userFile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => IMG_0003 (2).JPG ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\server\tmp\php924.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 1777374 ) ) )

Comment: and yes I checked into max_file_uploads with get_ini() and it showed 20. I'm only trying to upload 3 files for my own testing.

Comment: I have the same issue whether I use my localhost server or I use the server that the site is on. I can't understand the problem here.

Comment: Can you make it work if you don't use jQuery but have multiple `input` elements in the original HTML?

Comment: Did you check with a packet sniffer if multiple files are actually being uploaded?

Comment: Did you make sure the newly generated input elements are actually inside of your form?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. All my efforts were in vain, but finally I found a pretty good note at the PHP Manual. It's simple but suited me perfectly...

> "Multiple upload might not work if you use a table for displaying your
>   form inputs when `<form>` element is ***inside*** the `<table>` element. In this
>   case **only the first file will be uploaded**.
>
> Put the  `<form>`  element **outside** the  element to get it to work."

Follow this link for the full note, there is a function to rearrange the multiple upload file array in a easy-to-use manner.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: HTML code validation helped also. I had a faulty <td>